# continuous drawing (opencv)

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to draw following the movements of the mouse. It works ok.

When I move the mouse slowly, what is drawn looks continuous, but when I speed a little bit the mouse movement, I get discontinuous drawings.

How can I draw with the mouse continusouly

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

drawing=False # true if mouse is pressed
mode=True # if True, draw rectangle. Press 'm' to toggle to curve

# mouse callback function
def interactive_drawing(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy,drawing, mode

    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing=True
        ix,iy=x,y

    elif event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing==True:
            if mode==True:
                cv2.circle(img,(x,y),1,(0,0,255),-1)
                print x,y
    elif event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing=False
        if mode==True:
            cv2.circle(img,(x,y),1,(0,0,255),-1)
            #print x,y
            #cv2.line(img,(x,y),(x,y),(0,0,255),10)
    return x,y




img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

cv2.namedWindow('begueradj')
cv2.setMouseCallback('begueradj',interactive_drawing)
while(1):
    cv2.imshow('begueradje',img)
    k=cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF
    if k==27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Resulat I get:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the mouse moves fast, you cannot draw fast enough to keep up with the mouse events. To confirm this, modify your code to capture the mouse coordinates without drawing and add them in a list. Add a keypress handler to draw the captured points. If this is the case, you could draw a circle on a small transparent image once. You can then overlay that small image instead of drawing a circle which involves too many calculations in the space of a fraction of a second. Give this a shot and advise.

**Edit:**

As I said in the comment above,

> So you need to link the individual points with lines.

this is the only 'in live' drawing you can perform. Proof:

[image]

So you need to keep track of every pixel that you visit in order to draw a line between it and the next one to which your mouse moves:

```
cv2.line(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,0,255),10) # draw line between former and present pixel
ix=x # save former x coordinate
iy=y # save former y coordinate
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. I will save the points in a list and draw them later. That will work for sure continuously.

Comment: عرفت انك من الجزائر يا أخي في الله :-)

Comment: Please tell me how it goes. I'm curious to find out.

Comment: I did exactly what you said: the callbackfunction I use does not do anything as you advised me: first, I just displayed the pixels. Then I commented the displaying actions and replaced them with actions that append the pixels to the  a given list. I saved the list in the constructor of the class so that i can check it, update it any time. Then i read that list and change the color of those pixels. I simply implemented your idea :)

Comment: The only caveat with this path, isthat the pixels are colored after the mouse actions, not during them.

Comment: @Kabyle I am aware that this is not really a solution. It was mostly an investigative action. If it does confirm that the culprit is caused by drawing a circle at each mouse move, you might want to try using a small tranparent background image containing an opaque circle that has been pre-drawn. You can then use that as a sort of stamp in lieu of drawing a circle each time. By the way do you face the same problem when drawing  a segment from one pixel to another as you move the mouse?

Comment: Yes, same problem if I draw segment from pixels. I searched the whole web to see how the drawing is performed *in live* but did not find anything. I accepted your answer because my real goal is not this one properly said (this is just a small step in a larger program), however I am curious to see the solution for it, may be i will ask it an other time in a different question

Comment: I just ran your script. I removed the circle drawing and had a look at the coordinates that are printed. When moving fast, the coordinates are something like 10 pixels apart. I then thought a moment and came to the conclusion that the O.S. must have some limit on how often it fires the mousemove event.

Comment: I finally came across a web site stating that on Win XP the system setting generates an update every 15 ms. When moving the mouse around, you can easily calculate how many pixels you can travel in a tenth of a second taking into account that you can roughly move the width of the entire screen four times per second. To confirm what I am saying, move the mouse around the screen and see how often the pointer is repainted. It's not continuous. As such, I do not expect you will be able to do better.

Comment: Some other strategy / algorithm has to be followed. I opened mspaint on Windows and drawing quickly does not generate curves as expected from a continuous movement but generates segments instead. So you need to link the individual points with lines.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these precious information. I guess I do not need to ask a second separate question (even if yours fits my real needs in that you gave me an idea of storing the pixels somewhere which resolves my real problem, may be i did not express my real need through this example of code. If I wanted to ask the other it is just by pure curiosity). That is smart you tried that tool on Windows. It never came to my mind to test it. Your comments show you are a very curious person with a real scientific spirit. I appreciate that from You. Kind regards.

Comment: your idea in the last comment works so fine :) I displayed that through your answer with only the necessary code outlined by your own idea. Thank you again, regards